# Aspect ratio for image in div with equal height and width not kept in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have a solution that works in Chrome, IE and Safari but not in Firefox.

Please note that its essential to me that the image is in a div of floating size, preserving its aspect ratio, always being a perfect square. (just giving the image a border won't cut it)

The square-div, is accomplished by the .image-* classes. They work together as shown in the example I found here: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

If I open this solution in Firefox and make the window narrow enough, the image gets wider. The woman in the picture won't be happy ;-)

I want the image in the square div, to resize preserving its aspect ratio in Firefox as well, just as it does in the other browsers. What am I missing? What differs in Firefox's implementation? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<style>
    .image-container{
        position:relative;
        width: 60%;                 /*size relative parent element*/

        border: solid black 1px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .image-container:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-top: 100%;   /*aspect ratio, try: 50%, 200%, 75%, 56.25%*/
    }
    .image-container-content{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .image{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        flex-shrink: 0;     /*For IE so img doesn't get outside of frame*/
        width: auto;
    }

    .center-center{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .outer {
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<body>

<p>Image in square frame:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image-container-content center-center">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/people/9/sample%20picture/"
                 class="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Image not in frame (for visual comparison):</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/people/9/sample%20picture/"
             class="image">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome 39 behaves the same way that Firefox does, for me -- when the window is skinny, the image gets vertically squashed.  I don't know what the best trick is for preserving aspect ratios in this case, right now. Ultimately, i think you'll want to use `object-fit: scale-down` on the `<img>` element, which keeps the image content inside the `<img>` element's bounds & preserves its aspect ratio.  But that's not available in Firefox or IE yet. (I'm working on it in Firefox right now.)

Comment: Interesting to know that it doesn't work in old Chrome either... I noticed that if I don't use the center-center CSS, the one using flexbox to vertically center the image then the image resizes. One work-around would be to vertically center the image in some other way. But I don't know how. And it works so lovely on all the others with justify-content:center. Maybe we are missing something with the flexbox?